# Controlling Color Shades in Flot

Tags: flot

I have a bar chart where I need to limit the number of colors used, so that different bars may end up with the same color.  For example, if the colors are limited to Red and Blue and there are 6 bars (each its own series), then show them as:

Red Blue Red Blue Red Blue

(This is NOT 2 series repeating at each x axis.)

I have done this by creating a variable with an array of colors:

```
var availableColors = ["Red", "Blue"];
```

then in the configuration I have set:

```
colors: availableColors,...
```

This only sort of works.  The two colors do indeed repeat across all of the bars, but each time a color repeats in a new bar, it shows up in a different shade of that color.  (I intentionally have not made "Grey" one of those colors, so no 50 Shades of jokes.)

How do I keep the colors fixed on each bar so that I don't get shades of each color?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about this?

```
var availableColors = ["Red", "Blue", "Red", "Blue", "Red", "Blue"];
```

What happens with your array is the default behaviot of flot (see the [documentation](https://github.com/flot/flot/blob/master/API.md#customizing-the-data-series)):

> If there are more data series than colors, Flot will try to generate extra colors by lightening and darkening colors in the theme.

If the number of colors you need is variable, create the array dynamically in your script.

Comment: That seems to have fixed it. I read somewhere that you need to define at least 5 colors. Should 5 be enough in availableColors?

Comment: If you don't want flot to use lightened or darkened colors, you have to define at least as many colors as data series.

Comment: Thanks again.  Btw, instead of manually creating that list of colors, is there any way to access to Flot API to simply get their list of colors in order?  I couldn't quite find that.